# Please Id this plant

Tags: identification

Clicked this photo in a plant nursery. They told its name as 'Philishiyan' but I could not find any details on internet regarding this name. Please Id this plant.

[image: Please Id this plant]

Comment: Please could you give us some more details, where in the world is this? I am assuming that they gave you the local name, did they say anything else about it (flowers, fruit, uses?).

Comment: Its in India and a foliage plant. They showed me this as an alternative to palms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I got the name of this plant. Its called Filicium decipiens Sapindaceae.

Reference links are -

[Link 1](https://philipt.smugmug.com/Species/Species-F-K/Filicium-decipiens/i-tRsXSGC)
[Link 2](http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Fern%20Tree.html)